# Opencart checkout page slow speed

Tags: opencart

To confirm the order in checkout page, if the payment is bank transfer or cash that is not paypal, the loading time to complete the order is 38 seconds. How can I reduce loading time?  Using opencart version 2.1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Open `dev tools` go to `network` and reload the page...see which resources are  using up the most time and then you will have to go into them and investigate why. I have noticed that sometimes opencart runs a query more then once. you will have to find duplicate queries and remove them if this is the case